# How to draw grouped list

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I need to draw a grouped list in LaTeX as the figure below:

[image]

In MS Office I can draw it by means of SmartArt - grouped list. In LaTeX I looked for in smartdiagram and TikZ packages but I did not found it.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); the `positioning` library is used to position nodes relative to other ones; the `fit` and `backgrounds` libraries are used to place the surrounding frame with rounded corners in the background layer; some styles were defined for the blocks:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,fit}

\definecolor{bluei}{RGB}{83,116,191}
\definecolor{blueii}{RGB}{207,212,232}
\definecolor{greeni}{RGB}{135,200,81}
\definecolor{greenii}{RGB}{216,235,207}

\tikzset{
  myiblock/.style 2 args={
    draw=white,
    fill=#1,
    line width=1pt,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=1cm,
    align=center,
    text=white,
    font=\sffamily,
    text width=#2
  },
  myoblock/.style={
    fill=#1,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    inner xsep=10pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm and 1cm]
\node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm}]
  (info1)
  {Info about \\ one piece};
\node[myiblock={bluei}{2cm},below=of info1]
  (info2)
  {Other};
\node[above=3pt of info1,font=\sffamily]
  (title1)
  {Structure 1};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[myoblock=blueii,fit={(title1) (info2)}] {};  
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,node distance=3pt and 1cm]
\node[myiblock={greeni}{2cm}]
  (infoob1)
  {Info object 1};
\node[myiblock={greeni}{2cm},below=of infoob1]
  (infoob2)
  {Info object 2};
\node[myiblock={greeni}{2cm},below=of infoob2]
  (infoob3)
  {Info object 3};
\node[above=3 pt of infoob1,font=\sffamily]
  (title2)
  {Structure 2};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[myoblock=greenii,fit={(title2) (infoob3)}] {};  
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Gonzalo's solution could be the use of a `matrix` node. A `matrix` is a container of nodes and its dimensions are adjusted according the contents. This means that there's no need for `fit` and `background` libraries.

Even more with a `matrix of nodes`, declaring each list node is even easier.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\definecolor{bluei}{RGB}{83,116,191}
\definecolor{blueii}{RGB}{207,212,232}
\definecolor{greeni}{RGB}{135,200,81}
\definecolor{greenii}{RGB}{216,235,207}

\tikzset{
  myiblock/.style 2 args={
    draw=white,
    fill=#1,
    line width=1pt,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=1cm,
    align=center,
    text=white,
    font=\sffamily,
    text width=#2
  },
  myoblock/.style={
     matrix of nodes,
    fill=#1,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    inner xsep=10pt,
    draw=none,
    row sep=0.5cm
  },
  mylabel/.style={
    black, 
    minimum height=0pt
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [myoblock={blueii}, nodes={myiblock={bluei}{2cm}}]
  {|[label={[mylabel]Structure 1}]|{Info about \\ one piece}\\ 
  Other\\
  };

\matrix (B) [myoblock={greenii}, nodes={myiblock={greeni}{2cm}}, 
   row sep=3pt, right=5mm of A.north east, anchor=north west]
  {|[label={[mylabel]Structure 2}]|Info object 1 \\
   Info Object 2\\ 
   Info Object 3\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]